# Possible to list all DNS records on internal LAN?

Tags: dns

Are there any commands that you can run from linux to list created DNS names without being able to login to the DNS server and list them there? E.g. on internal LAN I would like to list available/created DNS names.

As an example I know there exists a few DNS names that contain `ansible` so it could be nice if I could do some regex search for existing DNS names containing `ansible`

Comment: What do you mean by "without having access" to the DNS server? Do you mean without logging in to it, or without being able to use its DNS service?

Comment: Updated post to make it more clear - I mean not being able to login to the DNS server.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The DNS server is the place to look for this. There may be some, possibly incomplete or outdated, caches somewhere, but if you want to know the DNS names, you need to access the DNS server.

It would very much surprise me if your system did not have access to DNS, unless you are operating in a non-endorsed way in your company (in that case: stop what you're doing). You could try `dig -tAXFR mycompany.intranet` to see if you get the information you need.

That being said:

- If you have a lot of Windows machines, you might get some information from the ADS
- If your company has an IPAM system, you might get the information there.